# Multiplication of two incidence matrices

Tags: matrices

After reading a bunch of articles about graph theory, I think that the problem I am working on involves incidence matrices. There are three classes B, P and L. I know the relationship of every instance of class B with every instance of class P and so on for instances of Class L and P as well.

I mapped them in two matrices X and Y. My goal is to find out which instances of Class B are related to instances of Class L. I did a matrix multiplication of few examples of X and Y, and it seems to provide me with correct answer every time, but I want to theoretically understand why is this working. I tried looking up what does a product of two incidence matrices mean, but cannot find something which would explain this in layman's terms.

$$
X_{Class B \times Class P}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
Y_{Class P \times Class L}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations

Comment: Thanks for reference. I read that and the one on [Heterogenous relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_relation). However, both of them only speak of relationship between a matrix and its transpose which is almost similar to what I asked, but still is less intuitive.

Comment: The part under the heading "composition in terms of matrices" is what you want.  Notice that the product has to be defined a bit differently from the ordinary matrix product, though.